# Merging two pandas DataFrames both on a subset of columns and the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two datasets that I want to combine into a single pandas dataframe. They look something like this:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'protein': ['A']*4 + ['B']*4,
    'repeat':range(1, 9),
    'measurement1': [numpy.nan]*4 + list(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
    'measurement2': list(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)) + [numpy.nan]*4,
    'measurement3': list(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)) + [numpy.nan]*4,
})


df2 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'protein': ['A']*2 + ['B']*2,
    'repeat':range(1, 5),
    'measurement1': list(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
    'measurement4': list(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
    'measurement5': list(numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
})

idx = ['protein', 'repeat']
df1.set_index(idx, inplace=True)
df2.set_index(idx, inplace=True)
```

The first:

```
>>> df1
```

```
                measurement1  measurement2  measurement3
protein repeat                                          
A       1                NaN      0.757366      0.858163
        2                NaN      0.453202      0.287777
        3                NaN      0.434762      0.044638
        4                NaN      0.825710      0.653887
B       5           0.732218           NaN           NaN
        6           0.380481           NaN           NaN
        7           0.444811           NaN           NaN
        8           0.569743           NaN           NaN
```

and the second

```
>>> df2
```

```
                measurement1  measurement4  measurement5
protein repeat                                          
A       1           0.342011      0.174242      0.071223
        2           0.416247      0.820345      0.048176
B       3           0.240464      0.767659      0.328830
        4           0.985637      0.459141      0.089130
```

How can I merge these dataframes so that I have something like this:

```
                measurement1  measurement2  measurement3  measurement4  measurement5
protein repeat                                                                      
A       1           0.721179      0.019207      0.189169      0.186984      0.316553
        2           0.425959      0.301376      0.677409      0.794600      0.668739
        3           0.675156      0.834304      0.022280      0.414653      0.263979
        4           0.667983      0.563201      0.841316      0.062459      0.584332
B       5           0.598407           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
        6           0.658570           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
        7           0.226620           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
        8           0.958272           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Comment: `df1.combine_first(df2).reset_index()` ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `df2` is wrong, there is only `A` level:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'protein': ['A']*4,
    'repeat':range(1, 5),
    'measurement1': list(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
    'measurement4': list(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
    'measurement5': list(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)),
})

idx = ['protein', 'repeat']
df2.set_index(idx, inplace=True)

print (df2)
                measurement1  measurement4  measurement5
protein repeat                                          
A       1           0.927584      0.741862      0.165938
        2           0.569004      0.048579      0.780998
        3           0.457412      0.708697      0.286537
        4           0.753526      0.839243      0.306470
```

So is possible use:

```
df = df2.combine_first(df1).reset_index()
df = df[df.columns[2:].tolist() + df.columns[:2].tolist()]
print (df)
   measurement1  measurement2  measurement3  measurement4  measurement5  \
0      0.539505      0.241686      0.894978      0.988329      0.963004   
1      0.626309      0.095530      0.043223      0.375186      0.341831   
2      0.005545      0.238250      0.301947      0.097038      0.798923   
3      0.484909      0.807791      0.980582      0.461909      0.798846   
4      0.463653           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
5      0.502216           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
6      0.313669           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
7      0.047340           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   

  protein  repeat  
0       A       1  
1       A       2  
2       A       3  
3       A       4  
4       B       5  
5       B       6  
6       B       7  
7       B       8
```

Comment: Yes `df2` was an slightly incorrect representation of my data - sorry. However, the strategy still applies and works for my actual data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A more extensive solution but not as clean as jezraels answer, is to use `pandas.merge` and after that `fillna` between the two `measurement1` columns.

This can can be safer in some cases then using `combine first`

**Note** I changed the second dataframe index, same way `jezrael` did.

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=['', '_2'])
df_merge['measurement1'].fillna(df_merge['measurement1_2'], inplace=True)
df_merge.drop('measurement1_2', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df_merge)
                measurement1  measurement2  measurement3  measurement4  \
protein repeat                                                           
A       1           0.947668      0.361499      0.679650      0.001189   
        2           0.335468      0.155245      0.651453      0.217520   
        3           0.249411      0.364105      0.395564      0.523953   
        4           0.550545      0.889828      0.592233      0.973457   
B       5           0.655718           NaN           NaN           NaN   
        6           0.052645           NaN           NaN           NaN   
        7           0.013689           NaN           NaN           NaN   
        8           0.640769           NaN           NaN           NaN   

                measurement5  
protein repeat                
A       1           0.841053  
        2           0.291956  
        3           0.097706  
        4           0.573144  
B       5                NaN  
        6                NaN  
        7                NaN  
        8                NaN
```

Comment: This is the answer to the strategy I was trying to use. Useful, Thanks.